# How do I convert my FAA PPL to the equivalent in the UK / Europe?

Tags: easa-regulations, ppl, caa-uk-regulations

I am returning to the UK and want to convert my FAA PPL to a UK PPL. Does anyone know the process for doing this?

I am getting lots of conflicting information.

Comment: Welcome to the site @EricLacey, there's plenty of questions about going the opposite direction, but none about coming to the UK that I know of. I suggest you contact the CAA and ask. EASA and the CAA tend to be stuffy on these types of things, so while the FAA will issue a license on the basis of a UK one, the CAA will likely make you re-test and pass all the exams.

Answer (score 2):

As a disclaimer, this answer is based on Googling, not on personal experience, and compared to the US the situation seems very complicated. I'd suggest contacting [the CAA](http://caa.co.uk/home/) directly; EASA delegates licensing to its member states, so the practical details depend on the country you're in. You can read about one person's experience [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/flying/comments/5i4q0m/howto_faa_to_easa_conversion/), although it's in Hungary, not the UK.

Anyway, it looks like there are two processes: validation and conversion. A validation is a temporary license valid for 12 months only (or 24 months, according to some sources), whereas a conversion gives you a full EASA license. The purpose of a validation seems to be to let you fly while you work on conversion; I couldn't find any definitive sources on the process.

As for conversion itself, the [requirements I found](https://aopa.de/ueber-uns/for-foreign-pilots/ppl-validation/ppl-validation.html) on various sites are consistent with [EASA's own information](https://www.easa.europa.eu/easa-and-you/general-aviation/licensing-general-aviation):

> If you hold a Private Pilot Licence obtained outside Europe or not
>   according to the relevant EASA licensing regulations, you can convert
>   it to an European one. In order to do this you will need to pass an
>   exam on Air Law and another exam on Human Performance. You also need
>   to undertake a skill test and have at least 100 hours as a pilot in
>   the relevant aircraft category.

That doesn't sound too bad, although I have no idea how much effort and expense there is in practice. If you're instrument rated, though, the requirements seem quite onerous compared to the US because of the large amount of theory required (this is from the same EASA source):

> Competence Based Instrument Rating (CB-IR): This rating is for those
>   who already have an Instrument Rating issued outside Europe (e.g.
>   FAA). This reduces the requirements of obtaining an Instrument Rating
>   to at least 80 hours of theory and 40 hours of instrument time, 25
>   hours of which must be training.

And to add more complication, it appears that the UK currently allows FAA license holders [to fly using their FAA license](https://www.caa.co.uk/News/New-Guidance-on-Third-Country-Licences/) but in the UK only, i.e. it isn't an EASA license and therefore not valid across Europe. There's an [ongoing discussion with EASA](https://www.aopa.co.uk/index.php/latest-news/item/219-holders-of-faa-pilot-licences-with-faa-class-3-medicals-exemption) about it, so it might not be a good long-term option but I really have no idea.

There's also something in the UK - and perhaps other countries? - called an NPPL, a [National Private Pilot License](https://www.caa.co.uk/General-aviation/Pilot-licences/UK-national-licences/NPPL--national-private-pilot-licence/). But that also has limitations, and isn't valid outside the UK.

Finally, although it's common to see N-registered aircraft in Europe, if you're a European resident then you can't fly them with just an FAA license. You [also need an EASA license](http://faa-aircraft-trust.com/american-pilots-license-to-fly-an-faa-registered-aircraft-in-europe).

Someone who's actually converted an FAA license to EASA could probably give you a better answer.