# Pilots diploma made in USA-nostrification in Europe. How it works -what are the procedures?

Tags: general-aviation

I am a Polish citizen and am presently enrolled in flight training in USA.
Upon graduation, I will have approximately 250 hours of flight time and the following certificates and ratings:

- PRIVATE PILOT
- INSTRUMENT RATING
- COMMERCIAL PILOT
- MULTI-ENGINE RATING

In addition I may also have the following:

- CERTIFIED FLIGHT INSTRUCTOR (CFI)
- CERTIFIED FLIGHT INSTRUCTOR-INSTRUMENT (CFI-I)
- CERTIFIED FLIGHT INSTRUCTOR-MULTI-ENGINE (CFM)

I have been led to believe that I may not be able to work in the United States and will have to return to Europe for employment.

**How much of this training and experience will be transferable to Europe?**

I understand that the ratings would not allow me to immediately be
employed in Europe, but I am hoping that the level of training and experience will at least be of value and can be transferred.

Does anybody know how to [nostrificate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nostrificate) a diploma from the USA to Europe?
Please advise me as to what I may expect after I finish school in USA and back to Europe what are costs, and what is the time necessary to nostrificate- transform all papers into Europe..

Will it be possible to get a job in USA airlines for not US citizen? on F1 visa?

If not what are the procedures to transfer a diploma to Europe and what is necessary to do it .where to look for help in that case?

Comment: The answers to your questions are what you should have researched BEFORE you started spending money on lots of training that might/not be transferrable. In practice, the US CPL is not transferrable to anything usable in Europe - the training is good for you, but the qualification at the end is not. And the CFI/I ratings are not recognised in Europe. You will have a lot to do when you get back, but you will need to talk to your local EASA to get the official words.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! The visa question is about immigration so you might get more information at [expats.SE](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/). Unfortunately we have very little information on this site about converting FAA to EASA licenses; [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/43932/62) may be the only one. But if you find out more information yourself please feel free to answer your own question, that's completely fine here.